# Using yii2 date range in active record

Tags: yii2, date-range

i have a date field in my database which has datetype as data type, how can i use active record to fetch data according to specific date range?

```
$model = ModelName::find()
        ->where(["date"=>"FROM '2015-06-21' TO '2015-06-27' ", "status"=>1])->all();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the correct way could be this:

```
$model = ModelName::find()->where(['between', 'date', "2015-06-21", "2015-06-27" ])
->andWhere(['status'=> 1])->all();
```

Comment: @priyankaahire   post a new question with your code and a clear explanation fo your problem .. and comment me the link for your question .. if i'm free i take a look

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318434/ho-to-write-between-query-in-yii2...This is a link Where I am adding new question