# How to write where Between query in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am passing `$start_date` and `$end_date` as parameter to compare them with `created` field in MySQL database table. I am using `yii2` framework.

Here is what I tried:

```
$modelStockDetails=StockDetails::find()->where(['BETWEEN', 'created', $start_date, $end_date])->andwhere(['receiving_order_id' =>$modelRecevingOrder->id,'deleted' => 'N'])->all();
```

which returns an empty array when values `$start_date` and `$end_date` are different from `created` date in the table.

But it returns an array containing the data when I pass `$start_date` which is exactly same as `created` date in the table.

Comment: What is the result without the `andWhere`?

Comment: Also try using `between` with lower case.

Comment: Have you had a look at the generated query to see if it looks like what you expect? that is what I would do. Then use that generated query in an SQL IDE? Does it work? that way you can debug the PHP?

Comment: The "created" field what type it is?

Comment: created field  is a timestamp type

Comment: And the $start_date and $end_date ?

Comment: $connection = \Yii::$app->getDb();
 $command = $connection->createCommand("select * from stock_details where DATE(created) BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' AND receiving_order_id='".$modelRecevingOrder->id."'"  );
$modelStockDetails = $command->queryAll();

Comment: This one working for me now

Comment: Thanks for giving  me advice

Answer (score 1):

Could be a problem related to the conversion of the input try using a str_to_date and literal Where 
(use a proper date format conversion based on your format im my sample  is  "%d-%m-%Y")

```
$modelStockDetails=StockDetails::find()
  ->where(' date(created) between STR_TO_DATE("'.  $start_date . '", "%d-%m-%Y" ) 
        AND   STR_TO_DATE("' .  $end_date . '", "%d-%m-%Y" )' )
  ->andwhere(['receiving_order_id' =>$modelRecevingOrder->id,'deleted' => 'N'])->all();
```

or for avoid the use of var in sql  you could use

```
$modelStockDetails=StockDetails::find()
->where(' date(created) between STR_TO_DATE(:start_date, "%d-%m-%Y" ) 
      AND   STR_TO_DATE( :end_date, "%d-%m-%Y" )', [':start_date' => $start_date, ':end_date' => $end_date] )
->andwhere(['receiving_order_id' =>$modelRecevingOrder->id,'deleted' => 'N'])->all();
```

Comment: actually in table created is timestamp, therefore I am using  DATE function and pass parameter created to DATE()